# Does an Item emit a signal when its position/size is changed in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a canvas that contains a few MouseAreas that can be dragged. The canvas draws some decoration between these items that cannot be expressed as native QML elements.

How can I initiate a redraw of the canvas when an Item changes size or position? I know that I need to call canvas.requestPaint(), but on which event? The only solution I found so far was calling requestPaint() within a timer, but I want to avoid that due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [QML documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-change-signal-handlers), each property of a `QML` component has an implicit signal associated with a change of value in the property:

> Signal handlers for property change signal take the syntax form `on<Property>Changed` where `<Property>` is the name of the property, with the first letter capitalized. For example, although the TextInput type documentation does not document a textChanged signal, this signal is implicitly available through the fact that TextInput has a text property and so it is possible to write an onTextChanged signal handler to be called whenever this property changes

Comment: If so, what property is it best to use that with to detect when the position and size are changed?

Comment: I haven't used QML in a long time but I think you want `onWidthChanged` or `onHeightChanged` and then `onXChanged` or `onYChanged`

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just hooking up both `onWidthChanged` and `onHeightChanged` and that seems to catch all the resizing I need. Thanks!